# ERR unknown command 'JSON.SET' - Rejson/Redis

Tags: redis, redisjson

I have followed the tutorial and run:

```
docker run -p 6379:6379 --name redis-rejson redislabs/rejson:latest
```

But when I try to run redis-cli and then json.get, I got:

```
ERR unknown command 'JSON.SET'
```

MODULE LIST return nil. Can anyone guide me on how to run rejson with docker? Appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

I found the problems. I run local redis and it use port 6379 already. When I map rejson docker 6379:6379, it conflicts. . Use different local port for rejson to map with docker port, for example 7000:6379. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are not loading the redis-json module. Solution is:

1. First stop redis server

   `brew services stop redis`
2. Then, run server with loading the module

   `redis-server --loadmodule ./your_release_directory/librejson.dylib`

Now you can `redis-cli` in other terminal.

Comment: I use the latest Redis docker image, where's this module located

Comment: You can check the build section from https://github.com/RedisJSON/RedisJSON repo @ahmedjaad